# Add new account to Twitter app on Samsung Tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 7.1-nougat, twitter, menu

I am on Samsung Galaxy Tab S2, Model SM-T715Y, running Android Version 7.71.1-release.15,
 trying to follow the instructions from
https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/managing-multiple-twitter-accounts
to add a new account to my Twitter app.

However I cannot find the "Add existing account" option as described.
The top menu shows:

```
"Share", "Drafts", "View Lists", "View Moments", "QR code"
```

but nothing about accounts. There is no "down arrow" icon.

The profile menu shows:

```
"Profile", "Lists", "Bookmarks", "Moments", "Twitter Ads", "Settings and privacy", "Help Center".
```

Clicking on "Settings and privacy" shows under my account:

```
"Account", "Privacy and safety", "Notifications", "Content preferences"
```

and under "General":

```
"Display and sound", "Data usage", "Accessibility", "Proxy", "About Twitter".
```

I don't see where else I could find that option.

Comment: is your app updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Swipe from left to right in the Twitter App
- Then Click the arrow pointing down near your name

[image]

- There is an option for **Create New Account** and **Add an Existing Account"

[image]

Reference [link](https://www.technologyhint.com/add-multiple-accounts-twitter/).

Comment: happy to help..